# How to configure mail Id for windows phone 8 application...?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing windows phone 8 application .

In my App i have feedback form page.

I need to receive mail from my app email id. not from user email id.

and Not Need windows phone mail compose screen.

I explain with my code and screen shots.

Step1: My XAML CODE

```
 <Button Name="Search" Margin="366,0,10,668" Click="Search_Click" >
 <Image Source="/Assets/Images/Icons/Forward.png" Height="54" Width="42"></Image>
 </Button>

 <StackPanel Name="content" Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="12,112,10,15">
        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox  Name="To" Text="gurunathan.n@gmail.com" Foreground="Gray"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Name="Subject" Text="Testing Subject" Foreground="Gray"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Text="Hi... This Is for Test" Name="Compose" Height="400"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
 </StackPanel>
```

Step 2: C# Code

```
 private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
        email.Body = Compose.Text;
        email.Subject = Subject.Text;
        email.To = To.Text;
        email.Show();
     }
```

Screen1-

[image: Mail Compose Screen]

gurunathan.n@gmail.com Is ----TO Address

Testing Subject Is        ----Subject

Hi..This is For test      ----Body

user click on compose mail button at top . next screen come like this...

Screen 2-

[image]

next it Show the Default mail compose screen of windows phone . [I need to avoid this screen] after click button directly mail to be send.

Screen 3-

[image]

My Main issue is now FROM mail id is taken from the phone configure mail id for example.

I use test@gmail.com in phone. now the mail send to gurunathan.n@gmail.com form test@gmail.com.

I not need mail send from user mail id(test@gmail.com).

For my app i have separate mail id like myapp@gmail.com.

I need to receive the mail form myapp@gmail.com form that mail i need the info this mail is send by test@gmail.com.

IF my question is not clear plz ask i explain more details...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Unless you use a third party service to send an email, the user is always in charge of email sending. You're talking about receiving mail as well...which you can't control without user consent.

Comment: Thank You for your response wiredprairie. I have three mail Id's 1.user mail Configure in Phone [user@gmail.com]                    2.To mail Id [myapp@gmail.com]                                   3.App mail Id [tavg@gmail.com]                       if user send mail from feedbackpage it contain only To-Subject-Body In To mail ID[myapp@gmail.com] is used . now i got one mail in myapp@gmail.com if i open it's show mail come user@gmail.com .but i need to receive mail from tavg@gmail.com in that mail user mail id must be show...

Comment: Plz tell me what are the third party service available for mail in WP8.

Comment: Most web hosts have SMTP available for general purpose e-mailing. Higher volume requires more effort. It's well documented. Finding a 3rd party for e-mail sending isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. A few web searches should find quite a few that may fit your needs (which still aren't clear).